# Sorting Python List Based on Column - Descending Order

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am using Backtrader optimizer functionality to evaluate the best parameter combination that I can use in my trading strategy. The output from the optimizer for each parameter set (Slow_EMA, Fast_EMA) along with it's value are added to the list and the code for the same is

```
val_list = [self.params.sl_maperiod, self.params.ft_maperiod,self.broker.getvalue()]
print (val_list)
```

the first column is Slow_EMA value and the second column is Fast_EMA value and the third column is the cash value that the optimizer generates for the Slow_EMA and Fast_EMA combination. I am providing the output below

```
[5, 20, 101416.90550000001]                                                                                       
[5, 21, 101717.35600000001]                                                                         
[5, 22, 101942.15999999999]                                                                            
[5, 23, 101938.65450000002]                                                                                   
[5, 24, 101785.45050000002]                                                                                  
[5, 25, 102084.91550000002]                                                                                     
[5, 26, 101634.87550000002]                                                                                 
[5, 27, 101835.576]                                                                                             
[5, 28, 101889.99200000001]                                                                                  
[5, 29, 101906.11300000001]
```

**I want to sort this output in a descending order based on column 3** such that the record with the highest value gets displayed at the top.

Please help me here

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to do this, one of the way is to use `sort()` method with `lambda` which will pass a particular value as a key in `sort()` method.

But, before that, encapsulate all the lists that you want to sort in a single list.

Sample code given below,

```
val_list_group = [[5, 20, 101416.90550000001], [5, 21, 101717.35600000001], [5, 22, 101942.15999999999], [5, 23, 101938.65450000002], [5, 25, 102084.91550000002], [5, 26, 101634.87550000002], [5, 27, 101835.576]]

val_list_group.sort(key = lambda x: x[2], reverse = True)
```

Read this article to know more, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sort-list-according-second-element-sublist/

Comment: When I tried it, I am getting the below error                                                                                                                                                                                              print(val_list.sort(key = lambda x: x[2], reverse = True))
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I think, you have not encapsulated all the lists that you want to sort in a single list. If yes, then please create a new list (eg. ```val_list_group```) and append every ```val_list``` in ```val_list_group``` list and then use sort method as given in answer on ```val_list_group```.

Updating the answer

Comment: If I try to add the val_list to val_list_group the output seems to be like this before I apply sorting ~~~[[1, 25, 101431.23749999999]]
[[1, 26, 101554.3095]]
[[1, 27, 101415.05750000001]]
[[1, 28, 101534.672]]
[[1, 29, 101522.76750000002]]
[[2, 25, 101498.80149999999]]
[[2, 26, 101602.75099999999]]
~~~ If I apply sorting on this as you have suggested I am getting "None" as output

Comment: You are probably printing like this, ```print(val_list_group.sort(key = lambda x: x[2], reverse = True))```  this will print ```None``` because ```sort()``` method returns ```None```.

Comment: You should print ```val_list_group``` instead, after sorting the list, like this,
```print(val_list_group.sort(key = lambda x: x[2], reverse = True))
print(val_list_group)
```  
It will print the sorted list

Comment: I tried, as you suggested. I am getting output, but it is the same output without sorting applied on column 3. It is like printing 'Val_List' directly

Comment: Please share your code, if possible.

Comment: def stop(self):
        val_list = [self.params.sl_maperiod, self.params.ft_maperiod,
                     self.broker.getvalue()]
        val_list_group = [val_list]
        val_list_group.sort(key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
        print(val_list_group)